# Does StackOverflow automatically filter what I see on the homepage?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, filtering

I'm trying to work out if there are vastly more questions on web development than on other topics, or whether my view of the homepage is being prefiltered- or both.

When I log onto the home page, I see a sea of JavaScript questions, and little else. However, the weekly newsletter features very little on this- it's largely C++, C# and more general theory questions. It's possible the questions on the weirder edges AngularJS are just too dull for the newsletter, but it's also possible that I'm on the end of some unasked for Facebook-style content filtering. I work as a web developer, so I'm certainly getting what I'd expect in that case.

So, does anyone know what is going on with this? Any answers much appreciated.

Comment: Simple: open Incognito/Private browser session and view the homepage. This will prove or disprove your assumption.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is "yes, there is content filtering in action on Stack Overflow". See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/.